# Вызов Restfull сервиса + безопасность

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Хочу реализовать вызов web api по https + каждый вызов должен быть аутентифицирован - в куках должен присутствовать токен который был создан отдельным запросом на ресурс для аутентификации того же сервиса.

Не подскажите в какую из направлений копать? 
Гугл отвечает только как обезопасить сервиса, но не как их вызывать.

Comment: в чем проблема? как сделать запрос?

Comment: скорее как организовать запрос так, что бы сначала токен вычислялся потом уже основной запрос.

Comment: Всм вычислялся? Нельзя при первом запросе билдить токен, а потом просто брать его из куки и отправлять на сервер для проверки?

Comment: Вот в этом и Вопрос - как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Небольшой пример того, как можно во время запроса проверить есть ли куки у пользователя, и если нет, то добавить их ему. Защищенный сервис можно вызвать через RestTemplate, добавив в хедер имеющиеся куки.

```
@RestController
public class MockController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public ResponseEntity mockEndpoint(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        Optional<Cookie> optionalCookie = extractCookies(request,"MyCookie");

        if (optionalCookie.isPresent()){
            return callProtectedService(optionalCookie.get());
        }

        else {
            String token = getTokenFromProtectedService();
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("MyCookie",token);
            response.addCookie("MyCookie",token);
            return callProtectedService(cookie);
        }

    }

    private Optional<Cookie> extractCookies(HttpServletRequest request,String cookieName) {
        return Arrays.stream(request.getCookies())
                .filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(cookieName))
                .findFirst();
    }
}
```

Comment: контроллер на стороне сервера или клиента?